# Create JS Double click not working in IPad

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs

I have added a createjs Double click event on a Movieclip, its working fine in Desktop.
But its not working in Touch Devices(IPad , Iphone). Will it work ? or is there a way to achieve it other than using timer on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable touch events when they are supported using something like this

```
if (createjs.Touch.isSupported()) {
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
}
```

After you don't need the touch events anymore, make sure you disable them using

```
createjs.Touch.disable(stage);
```

Comment: I have enabled the touch, pressup and other events are working fine. Its the double click which is not firing.